# "const T const" in parameter declaration

Tags: c++

I came across this code the other day:

```
template< class T > 
T findMax(const T const * data, 
        const size_t const numItems) { 
// Obtain the minimum value for type T 
T largest = 
    std::numeric_limits< T >::min(); 
for(unsigned int i=0; i<numItems; ++i) 
if (data[i] > largest) 
largest = data[i]; 
return largest; 
}
```

Why do the parameters each contain two `const`s?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between const int\*, const int \* const, and int const \*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Comment: I retract my close vote since that is for `const T * const` not `const T const *`.

Comment: @clcto Still, the answers there teach how to read the `const`s in general. Granted, they may be redundant here.

Comment: Unclear if you talk about  `data` or about `numItems` but anyway one `const` is redundant with the other for each one..

Comment: It means `error: duplicate 'const'`.

Comment: Somebody wanted to be **really, really** sure that `numItems` can't be modified.

Comment: Actually g++ produces compilation error

Comment: I bet this compiles fine by MSVC

Comment: @Sir Visto  "Why do the parameters each contain two consts?" - The reason is single: the author of the code does not know C++ and can not write programs. The function is wrong and does not make sense.

Answer (score 8):

There's no meaningful reason for that. Moreover such explicit repetition of  `const` qualifiers is illegal in C++. The code is ill-formed.

> **7.1.6.1 The cv-qualifiers [dcl.type.cv]**
>
> **1** There are two cv-qualifiers, const and volatile. Each cv-qualifier shall appear at most once in a cvqualifier-seq.

It is possible to introduce redundant `const`s in a C++ declaration, but that would require "hiding" previous `const`s inside a typedef-name. In that form the declatration would be legal and the redundant qualifiers would be ignored.

Comment: Actually interesting question comes in mind - does it make any sense to put them both?

Comment: @Slava: if you mean `const volatile`, yes, it does make sense. Think of e.g. a memory-mapped clock. `const` means you can't write (can't set the clock), `volatile` guarantees (well.. tries to do) that the clock will be read in the appropriate time.

Answer (score 2):

One of the `const` modifiers is redundant; having two here is doing nothing more than one on its own (I'd be surprised if this didn't emit a warning at least).

What the author probably meant was `const T* const`, which is a constant pointer to a constant instance of `T`.